# Change Facebook Login Button appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change Facebook login button default appearance with my custom one.

[this is the default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOgK8.png)

[this is how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJjHc.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Custom login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced#custom-login-button)

```
// Add this to the header of your file
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

// Add this to the body
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Add a custom login button to your app
  UIButton *myLoginButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  myLoginButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
  myLoginButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,180,40);
  myLoginButton.center = self.view.center;
  [myLoginButton setTitle: @"My Login Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

  // Handle clicks on the button
  [myLoginButton 
    addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  // Add the button to the view
  [self.view addSubview:myLoginButton];
}

// Once the button is clicked, show the login dialog
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login
    logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
          fromViewController:self
                     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
      NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];
}

@end
```