# Remove facebook login button changing to logout

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

In my app I am implementing login with facebook but I have noticed that every time after I login to facebook the login button changes to logout and on click of logout I am able to logout from facebook.But I don't want the default facebook login button to change to logout.How to do this? I am trying for weeks and could not achieve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092974/5461400

Comment: @HarshalValanda It is working but everytime it shows the login screen though i have logged in already

Comment: check that user already login in facebook or not

Comment: @HarshalValanda Thank you .Its working as expected